# Securing Eureka in Spring cloud

Tags: spring-cloud

I am curious about what options I have for securing a service connecting (registering and getting disco info) to eureka.  Obviously I want to turn security on in Eureka and specify a username password for service.

One question that I have is how do services trying to connect to eureka specify their credentials?  Is it through the specification of the zone and what is the format of this reference?

*** I actually the answer to the above question and posted below, But still wonder about the following

As well, can I specify more strenuous security mechanisms and if so, which and how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, turns out that after you post an question is when suddenly you discover a way of doing.

I have figured out the part of my question:

in the Eureka server put this

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: true
  user:
      name: user # login username
      password: password
```

In you service then put this

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://user:password@localhost:8761/eureka/
```

After this services are authenticating to Eureka nd Eureka will reject any service without these credentials.

So Now to the second part of my question.  What other ways can I secure this connection that are more secure?

Comment: What are your concerns with that? Do you have a suggestion for something that is "more secure"?

Comment: I guess a application.yml with a use/password is probably ok for most instances.  I was wondering what other ways I could secure this besides this?

Comment: Upvoted. BTW, how did you find these properties? I see something else in the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_security). I'm wondering how could I specify them separately without embedding in the URL?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar you canfind these properties here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: The used protocol is HTTP which can be eavesdropped, you should use HTTPS.