# How to secure spring cloud eureka service with basic auth?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I set up multiple instances of eureka servers on the same host. They are using  host names eureka-primary, secondary and tertiary which are defined as the localhost aliases in the hosts file and everything is working just fine - they are all visible and available to each other as different instances.

The problem starts when I try to secure eureka instances with `basic auth` and this. The idea is add spring security dependency, to specify the security user and password on eureka servers, and to put these credentials in the `defaultZone` urls (configs are below), but this does not seem to work.

Eureka instances can't even register to each other and when I try to access eureka web portal I am prompted with login form and then redirected to dashboard. All dashboards are working fine and need credentials to be accessed.

I am using spring cloud `Finchley.RC1` with spring boot `2.0.1.RELEASE` and the same version of `spring-boot-starter-security` and `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server`.

**Eureka server pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>rs.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>eurekaServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>eurekaServer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RC1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

**Eureka server application.yml**

```
---
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: admin
      password: admin
  profiles: primary
  application:
    name: eureka-server-clustered   
server:
  port: 8011  
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-primary       
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true        
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://admin:admin@eureka-secondary:8012/eureka/,http://admin:admin@eureka-tertiary:8013/eureka/

---
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: admin
      password: admin
  profiles: secondary
  application:
    name: eureka-server-clustered      
server:
  port: 8012
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-secondary       
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true        
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://admin:admin@eureka-primary:8013/eureka/,http://admin:admin@eureka-tertiary:8011/eureka/

---
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: admin
      password: admin
  profiles: tertiary
  application:
    name: eureka-server-clustered      
server:
  port: 8013
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-tertiary       
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true    
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://admin:admin@eureka-primary:8011/eureka/,http://admin:admin@eureka-secondary:8012/eureka/
```

**Microservice bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: someService
server:
  port: 0 
eureka:  
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://admin:admin@localhost:8011/eureka/,http://admin:admin@localhost:8012/eureka/,http://admin:admin@localhost:8013/eureka/
```

What am I doing wrong?

***EDIT**

I already found multiple solutions like this one [Securing Eureka in Spring cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974752/securing-eureka-in-spring-cloud?rq=1), but none of them really fixed my problem - as you can see our configurations are identical.

Comment: Yes. Thanks, Dusan
This is the only way to solve this issue It seems that the client register themselves to eureka using a post request which is protected by CSRF as default security settings
So the only way is to override these settings by extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and disable the CSRF

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved!

**TL;DR**
The problem was the `CSRF` and for some reason spring couldn't authenticate user configured in `application.yml`

So I had to override configure methods from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to disable csrf and create inMemory user. Also removed spring.security.user attributes from application.yml.

**Eureka server `application.yml` now looks like:**

```
---
spring:
  profiles: primary
  application:
    name: eureka-server-clustered   
server:
  port: 8011  
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-primary       
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true        
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://admin:admin@eureka-secondary:8012/eureka,http://admin:admin@eureka-tertiary:8013/eureka
---
spring:
  profiles: secondary
  application:
    name: eureka-server-clustered      
server:
  port: 8012
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-secondary       
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true        
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://admin:admin@eureka-primary:8013/eureka,http://admin:admin@eureka-tertiary:8011/eureka

---
spring:
  profiles: tertiary
  application:
    name: eureka-server-clustered     
server:
  port: 8013
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-tertiary       
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true    
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://admin:admin@eureka-primary:8011/eureka,http://admin:admin@eureka-secondary:8012/eureka
```

**Newly created `WebSecurityConfig` class:**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
        .withUser("admin").password("admin")
        .authorities("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
              .and()
              .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue with Greenwich.SR1.
Enabled security with  `spring.security.user.name` allowed me to login with username/password but my services could't register with Eureka service.
I made it work, and as mentioned above, the cause was indeed `CSRF`
This fixes it:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/eureka/**");
        super.configure(http);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Import spring-security in your pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And put this in your application.yaml :

```
security:
  user:
    name: admin
    password: password
```

And it should work !

EDIT : I already made this, here the simpliest code that allow you to achieve this, I seggest you start from here :

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>vg.step</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka.server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>vgstepeurekaserver</name>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.cloud-version>1.4.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.cloud-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.cloud-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Cloud -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>application*.yaml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

src/main/resources/application.yaml :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: @project.name@

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-server
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka

server:
  port: 8002

security:
  user:
    name: admin
    password: password
```

src/main/java/vg/step/eureka/server/Application.java :

```
package vg.step.eureka.server;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the text, I already have `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency, and as you can see in the attached eureka's application.yml, the config you recommend already exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I can see you are using 1.4.4.RELEASE, and my version is 2.0.1.RELEASE.