# JSON decoding error: Root name 'timestamp' does not match expected Eureka +spring security + Docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker-compose, netflix-eureka

I am securing the Eureka server with spring security, the eureka server and config server is dockerized in a container and the config server is registered with the Eureka server

[image]

Now I am trying to register other services to the Eureka, Other services are running from IDE they are not dockerized. I am using discovery first approach

## Eureka server

```
server:
  port: 8761

# Discovery Server Access
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
  serviceUrl:
    defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  security:
    basic:
      enabled: true
    user:
      name: fetebird
      password: fetebird
```

## Config Server

```
server:
  port: 8085

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://fetebird:fetebird@fetebird-eurekaservice:8761/eureka/
```

## Other service

```
spring:
  application:
    name: APIGATEWAY-SERVICE
  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        service-id: CONFIG-SERVER
        enabled: true
```

## Error

```
org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Root name 'timestamp' does not match expected ('applications') for type [simple type, class com.netflix.discovery.shared.Applications]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Root name 'timestamp' does not match expected ('applications') for type [simple type, class com.netflix.discovery.shared.Applications]
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.netflix.discovery.shared.Applications["timestamp"])
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.processException(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:215) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/?regions=us-east-1 [DefaultClientResponse]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.processException(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:215) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.decode(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:173) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.lambda$decodeToMono$1(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:159) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:330) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1782) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:427) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:210) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.request(FluxReceive.java:121) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:155) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.request(FluxPeek.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.request(FluxPeek.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:155) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCollect.java:112) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeek.java:163) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeek.java:163) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:300) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.lambda$subscribe$2(FluxReceive.java:138) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1679) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.WebClientEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(WebClientEurekaHttpClient.java:143) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.WebClientEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(WebClientEurekaHttpClient.java:124) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.config.EurekaConfigServerBootstrapConfiguration.lambda$eurekaConfigServerInstanceProvider$0(EurekaConfigServerBootstrapConfiguration.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerInstanceProvider.getConfigServerInstances(ConfigServerInstanceProvider.java:50) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration$HeartbeatListener.refresh(DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java:120) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration$HeartbeatListener.startup(DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java:106) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration$HeartbeatListener.onApplicationEvent(DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java:98) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at fete.bird.fetebirdapigateway.FeteBirdApiGatewayApplication.main(FeteBirdApiGatewayApplication.java:13) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Root name 'timestamp' does not match expected ('applications') for type [simple type, class com.netflix.discovery.shared.Applications]
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.netflix.discovery.shared.Applications["timestamp"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportPropertyInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1499) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportPropertyInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1515) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._unwrapAndDeserialize(ObjectReader.java:2188) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2054) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1431) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.decode(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:168) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.lambda$decodeToMono$1(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:159) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:330) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1782) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:427) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:210) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.request(FluxReceive.java:121) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:155) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.request(FluxPeek.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.request(FluxPeek.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:155) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCollect.java:112) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeek.java:163) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeek.java:163) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:300) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.lambda$subscribe$2(FluxReceive.java:138) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.8.RELEASE.jar:0.9.8.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

## Docker compose (Application is running successfully on the Docker)

```
version: '3'
services:
    fetebird-eurekaservice:
        container_name: FeteBird-EurekaService
        build:
            context: ../../Eureka-Service-Registry/
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: fetebird/eurekaservice
        ports:
            - "8761:8761"
        networks:
            - spring-cloud-network
        volumes:
            - ./fetebird-eurekaservice/data:/data
        logging:
            driver: json-file
    
    fetebird-configserver:
        container_name: FeteBird-ConfigServer
        build:
            context: ../../FeteBird-ConfigServer
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: fetebird/configserver
        ports:
            - "8085:8085"
        links:
            - fetebird-eurekaservice
        depends_on:
            - fetebird-eurekaservice
        networks:
            - spring-cloud-network
        volumes:
            - ./fetebird-configserver/data:/data
        logging:
            driver: json-file                   
networks:
    spring-cloud-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: This might happen when URL is incorrect of **Eureka**. https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/issues/1006#issuecomment-495795485

Comment: I guesss you need your clients in the Docker as well. Otherwise `network_mode=host` may be way forward in your case.

Comment: Its not the client issue, if I remove the spring security everything works, but when I add spring security it is happing.

Comment: I see, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51024117/6332074) and [this](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-eureka-server.html#_securing_the_eureka_server) might help.

Answer (score 7):

Solved this by correcting Eureka URL
eureka:
client:
serviceUrl:
defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}